# Handling dynamic IP in Django ALLOWED_HOSTS with nginx

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having issues with what i believe is my nginx.conf which is causing the instance to be restarted again and again, as the health-checks fail on my managed container service.

I'm running my setup in AWS Lightsail Containers, where I have three containers running:

- nginx
- django
- nextjs

When publishing a new release on my AWS Lightsail instance it runs fine for a few minutes, then I hit a 503 error, which causes the instance to reboot - run a few minutes then reboot again.

Looking at the logs I can see that the health-check failed, and django throws and error saying that I should add the request IP to the allowed hosts:

```
[28/Aug/2021:13:56:23] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'x.x.x.x'. You may need to add 'x.x.x.x' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[28/Aug/2021:13:56:23] Bad Request: /health.txt
```

The problem is that my lightsail container service does not have a static IP (nor do I believe I can get a static IP).

My current nginx.conf is below (feedback is appreciated). **My question** here is how should I deal with this issue? I feel like setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` is not a great approach. Can I hardcode the host for the healthcheck or similar?

**nginx.conf:**

```
upstream backend {
    server ${BACKEND_HOST}:${BACKEND_PORT};
}
upstream frontend {
    server ${FRONTEND_HOST}:${FRONTEND_PORT};
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

    location /robots.txt {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

    location /health.txt {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

    location /api {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }

    location /admin {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Comment: For your nginx conf, you can do `location ~ ^/(first|second|third)` when you treat locations the same

Comment: Thanks @Amin, I'll change that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use AWS EC2, to pass the health check I get the ip of the instance dynamically and then I insert it into ALLOWED_HOSTS (I think it should work also for Lightsail Containers):

```
import requests

def get_instance_ip():
    try:
        ip = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4').text
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return None
    return ip

AWS_IP = get_ec2_instance_ip()

if AWS_IP is not None:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS += [AWS_IP]
```

You can also create a middleware that always returns a 200 status code for the path used by health check (insert the custom middleware before `django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware` in `MIDDLEWARE` to avoid `Invalid HTTP_HOST header` error).

Comment: Hm, I like both ideas! The issue with the first suggestion (thanks for the code example) would be that I don't have the endpoint to ask for the latest dynamically set IP? The second one with middleware seems like a nice simple fix! However it does seem kind of hacky?

Comment: @Olsson the endpoint is equal for all EC2 instances. Lightsail Containers are built on the top of EC2, so I think that the endpoint i wrote should work.

Comment: I thought it worked, since it launched fine with health-checks. However it seems to come back? I tried the middleware approach, basically `if request.path == '/health.txt' ... return HttpResponse("...", status=200)`. However I still keep getting 503's and `Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'x.x.x.x'. You may need to add 'x.x.x.x' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.`...

Comment: @Olsson Did you insert your middleware before the security middleware (your custom middleware must the first in the `MIDDLEWARE` list in your settings)?  Did you configure AWS to use that path for security check (by default it uses "/")? Does health check continue fail or that error compares from time to time with the first approach?

Comment: I think I've solved it with your code-snippet above. Placed that at the top of settings and appended the IP. The middlware was placed before the security middleware, so not sure why certain requests kept avoiding that. I didn't have proper logging to have enough insight. Lightsail logs are a mess.